# Java Aggregate Operations vs Anonymous class suggestion

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

In this program, let’s say I have a class Leader that I want to assign to a class Mission. The Mission requires a class Skill, which has a type and a strength. The Leader has a List of Skills. I want to write a method that assigns a Leader (or a number of leaders) to a Mission and check if the Leaders’ combined skill strength is enough to accomplish the Mission.

```
public void assignLeaderToMission(Mission m, Leader... leaders) {
    List<Leader> selectedLeaders = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(leaders));
    int combinedStrength = selectedLeaders
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(l -> l.getSkills()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(s -> s.getType() == m.getSkillRequirement().getType())
                            .mapToInt(s -> s.getStrength())
                            .sum())
            .sum();
    if(m.getSkillRequirement().getStrength() > combinedStrength)
        System.out.println("Leader(s) do not meet mission requirements");
    else {
        // assign leader to mission
    }
}
```

Is this the appropriate way to use a stream with lambda operations? NetBeans is giving a suggestion that I use an anonymous class, but I thought that lambas and aggregate operations were supposed to replace the need for anonymous classes with a single method, or maybe I am interpreting this incorrectly.
In this case, I am accessing a List<> within a List<> and I am not sure this is the correct way to do so. Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe it could be made clearer by using `flatMap` (see example here: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_8_flatmap_example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using lambda expressions here. Netbeans just *offers* that code trans­for­ma­tion, since is is possible (and Netbeans can do the transformation for you). If you accept the offer and let it convert the code, it very likely starts offering converting the anonymous class to a lambda expression as soon as the conversion has been done, simply because it is (now) possible.

But if you want to improve your code, you should not use raw types, i.e. use

```
List<Leader> selectedLeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(leaders));
```

instead. But if you just want a `List<Leader>` without needing support for `add` or `remove`, there is no need to copy the list into an `ArrayList`, so you can use

```
List<Leader> selectedLeaders = Arrays.asList(leaders);
```

instead. But if all you want to do, is to stream over an array, you don’t need a `List` detour at all. You can simply use `Arrays.stream(leaders)` in the first place.

You may also use `flatMap` to reduce the amount of nested code, i.e.

```
int combinedStrength = Arrays.stream(leaders)
    .flatMap(l -> l.getSkills().stream())
    .filter(s -> s.getType() == m.getSkillRequirement().getType())
    .mapToInt(s -> s.getStrength())
    .sum();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did not really understand the flatmap, though I looked further into it and it is definitely the answer to my issue. And thank you for the other advice regarding just streaming through the array to prevent an unnecessary conversion. I didn't realize you can create a List<> without creating an ArrayList, LinkedlList, etc. I thought it was just the interface, so those methods are helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Lambda must be concise so that it is easy to maintain. If the lambda expression is lengthy, then the code will become hard to maintain and understand. Even debugging will be harder. 
More details on [Why the perfect lambda expression is just one line](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-java8idioms6/index.html) can be read here.

**The perilously long lambda**

To better understand the benefits of writing short, concise lambda expressions, consider the opposite: a sprawling lambda that unfolds over several lines of code:

```
System.out.println(
values.stream()
  .mapToInt(e -> {     
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= e; i++) {
      if(e % i == 0) {
        sum += i;
      }
    }

    return sum;
  })
  .sum());
```

Even though this code is written in the functional style, it misses the benefits of functional-style programming. Let's consider the reasons why.

**1. It's hard to read**

Good code should be inviting to read. This code takes mental effort to read: your eyes strain to find the beginning and end of the different parts.

**2. Its purpose isn't clear**

Good code should read like a story, not like a puzzle. A long, anonymous piece of code like this one hides the details of its purpose, costing the reader time and effort. Wrapping this piece of code into a named function would make it modular, while also bringing out its purpose through the associated name.

**3. Poor code quality**

Whatever your code does, it's likely that you'll want to reuse it sometime. The logic in this code is embedded within the lambda, which in turn is passed as an argument to another function, mapToInt. If we needed the code elsewhere in our program, we might be tempted to rewrite it, thus introducing inconsistencies in our code base. Alternatively, we might just copy and paste the code. Neither option would result in good code or quality software.

**4. It's hard to test**

Code always does what was typed and not necessarily what was intended, so it stands that any nontrivial code must be tested. If the code within the lambda expression can't be reached as a unit, it can't be unit tested. You could run integration tests, but that is no substitute for unit testing, especially when that code does significant work.

**5. Poor code coverage**

Lambdas that were embedded in arguments were not easily extracted as units, and many showed up red on the coverage report. With no insight, the team simply had to assume that those pieces worked.